# Extended charachter code pages

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, windows-xp, .net-4.0

I was trying to Validate characters (the extended ones) and i see that in various PC's they have in deferent places the extended characters. I meane we are not see the same ASCII code number for a certain character (not in Latins).
Now My issue is what i have to do when my program starts to use always a certain ASCII code table? 
For extended character of course.

Comment: I don't understand your question. .NET uses UTF-16 internally, so I don't see what ASCII has to do with things. Can you explain what you are doing, what is not working and provide code samples?

Comment: Dear Oded, thank you very much for your interest in my question. That what i want to do is to validate characters entry in various text boxes. I'm working in two PC's (office and home) in my office i use the extended character table UTF-8 (i think was that). but now in my office i see that the extended character code is in deferent numbers (places). So when this project will populated i don't know if my validation function will work or not.

Comment: @Lefteris - in a textbox it should make no difference; the strings are **always** UTF-16. Where *exactly* are you seeing a difference? Can you post code that illustrates how you are seeing this issue?

Comment: What i use for validation is this:  91 To 96, 123 To 126, 160 To 254, 8, 32 For the Greek characters validation

Comment: @Lefteris - is that comparing the `char` values? That should simply work.

Comment: Marc, Yes i'm comparing ascii(character) with there numbers

Comment: The issue is that when i'm taking the project in a deferent PC the ascii numbers are changed

Comment: @Lefteris - this next bit is important: `char` values **are not ASCII** - they are UTF-16. The `char` values should be the same **everywhere**, since they are unicode code-points.

Comment: Thank you very much Marc. Thank you for all of your assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue generally relates (since .NET strings are UTF-16) only to reading and writing text files. In which case, just use `Encoding.GetEncoding(codePage)` to choose the appropriate encoding, and use this when access any text files. All standard inbuilt text/file utility operations will take an encoding, for example:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("foo.txt", encoding);
```

Comment: I never use in my code the Encoding.GetEncoding(codePage). Sould i use that in order to have always a certain code page in my project?

Comment: @Lefteris - when it comes to **file access**, yes. This isn't project-wide, and must be specified each time you open a file as text.

Comment: Well you see Marc my aim is to validate characters entered from the keyboard in some certain textBoxes

Comment: @Lefteris - re that Greek codepage, either `Encoding.GetEncoding(28597)` or `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7")` should work for that.

Comment: @Lefteris - re validation; unless you are talking to a file etc, **it shouldn't matter** - in a `string`, there **is** no codepage; the characters are the same. The codepage only determines how *bytes* (in a file etc) are mapped to code-points; but in-memory you **only** have code-points.

Comment: Dear Marc Please assist me on that: Where do i write this Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-7")? In my Load sub in the main form or on each form will open each time?

Comment: @Lefteris - you would only use `Encoding.GetEncoding` when talking to a file (or other byte-stream). You should **not need this** when working inside a form.